# Possibility of Corruption: Reading Excel Files with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

We are in the design phase for product. The idea is that the code will read a list of values from Excel into SQL.

The requirements are as follows:

1. Workbook may be accessed by multiple users outside of our program
2. Workbook must remain accessible (i.e. not be corrupted) should something bad occur while our program is running
3. Program will be executed when no users are in the file

Right now we are considering using `pandas` in a simple manner as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    from pandas import ExcelFile

    df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')

    """Some code to write df in to SQL"""
```

If this code goes offline with the Excel still open, is there ANY possibility that the file will remain locked somewhere in my program or be corrupted?

To clarify, we envision something catastrophic like the server crashing or losing power.

Searched around but couldn't find a similar question, please redirect me if necessary. 
I also read through Pandas read_excel documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: The file will only be open until the `read_excel` call returns.

Comment: If your code only reads the file, then it can't corrupt it. If you plan to write to the file, then you'll need to take precautions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you provide, from my reading of the pandas and xlrd code, the given file will only be opened in read mode. That should mean, to the best of my knowledge, that there is no more risk in what you're doing than in reading the file any other way - and you have to read it to use it, after all.

If this doesn't sufficiently reassure you, you could minimize the time the file is open and, more importantly, not expose your file to external code, by handing pandas a `BytesIO` object instead of a path:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.BytesIO(open('File.xlsx', 'rb').read())
df = pd.read_excel(data, sheetname='Sheet1')

# etc
```

This way your file will only be open for the time it takes to read it into memory, and pandas and xlrd will only be working with a copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks! Selected as the answer. Would be great if anyone could provide a bit more documentation.